# Sign up / log in is not greyed out in read only mode on the SE dropdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange-button, read-only

Greyed over there but not here:

[image]

I think they should both be greyed out, or left alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's a fair observation, and is easy enough to fix; coming to a deploy near you soon...

Comment: Which one have you chosen?

Comment: @Tim grey it out; it turns out that this is simply a matter of giving it the right css classes to tell it that it is a login link; after that, the css will automatically dim it when the page is readonly.

Comment: Oh okay, nice an easy - I could do that ;-)